# How to fix font rendering with GDI+?

Tags: c++, gdi+, gdi

When drawing text using GDI+, the font is not rendered the way I need. Compared to using GDI, the letters are less 'bold' and the edges are smudgy. The code sample below shows the 2 implementations I have tested with.

```
static const std::wstring fontFamily(L"Arial Narrow");
static const int pointSize = 36;

#if 1 // Using GDI+
static const std::wstring text(L"Using GDI+");
VOID OnPaint(HDC hdc)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);

    Font font(fontFamily.c_str(), pointSize, FontStyle::FontStyleBold, UnitPoint);
    SolidBrush brush(Color(255, 0, 0, 0));

    graphics.DrawString(
      text.c_str()
    , text.length()
    , &font
    , PointF(10, 10)
    , &brush
    );
}

#else // Using GDI

static const std::wstring text(L"Using GDI");
VOID OnPaint(HDC hdc)
{
    int nHeight = -::MulDiv(pointSize, ::GetDeviceCaps(hdc, LOGPIXELSY), 72);
    HFONT hf = ::CreateFont(
      nHeight
    , 0
    , 0
    , 0
    , FW_BOLD
    , 0
    , 0
    , 0
    , DEFAULT_CHARSET
    , OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS
    , CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS
    , DEFAULT_QUALITY
    , DEFAULT_PITCH
    , fontFamily.c_str()
    );

    ::SelectObject(hdc, hf);

    RECT bounds;
    SetRect(&bounds, 10, 10, 300, 300);

    ::DrawText(hdc, text.c_str(), text.length(), &bounds, 0);

    ::DeleteObject(hf);
}
#endif
```

Here are the screenshots taken with both methods

[image: Using GDI]

[image: Using GDI+]

The screenshots don't show the difference in sharpness very well, but when sending it to a printer, the difference is very outspoken. The text printed with GDI+ is not even really black, but more towards a grey color.

I have tried the methods Graphics::SetTextRenderingHint, SetCompositingMode, SetCompositingQuality and SetInterpolationMode, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I also tried to combine GDI and GDI+, i.e. create the font using CreateFont and then instantiate Gdiplus::Font(HDC, HFONT), but then I can't get the size right.

Is there a way to get the GDI+ font to render exactly like GDI?

Comment: You are just not getting the same font, hard to guess why.  Note the handle leak in your GDI version, you are forgetting to restore the old font handle.

Comment: That is one of the reasons I need it to work in GDI+, less worrying about resource leaks :)